# Windsor TypedFactoryFacility broken?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, factory-pattern

I'm trying to create a typed factory as per [Windsor's example](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx).  This is my factory interface:

```
public interface ICustomJsonResultFactory
{
    JsonResult Create();
}
```

In my global.asax, I'm setting up the Windsor container by first adding the following two facilities:

```
.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

After that's done, I register my components:

```
Component.For<JsonResult>()
    .ImplementedBy<CustomJsonResult>()
    .LifestyleTransient(),
Component.For<ICustomJsonResultFactory>()
    .AsFactory())
```

One of my controllers has a `ICustomJsonResultFactory` property.  When I try resolving the controller, I get the following in my logs:

```
Castle.Core.DependencyResolution: DEBUG 8 - 
    Client:     DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector / ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
    Model:      Dependency 'getMethodsResolveByName' type 'System.Boolean'
    Dependency: True
Castle.Core.DependencyResolution: DEBUG 8 - 
    Client:     DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector / ITypedFactoryComponentSelector
    Model:      Dependency 'fallbackToResolveByTypeIfNameNotFound' type 'System.Boolean'
    Dependency: False
Castle.Core.DependencyResolution: DEBUG 8 - 
    Client:     TypedFactoryInterceptor
    Model:      Dependency 'kernel' type 'Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal'
    Dependency: Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel
Castle.Core.DependencyResolution: DEBUG 8 - 
    Client:     TypedFactoryInterceptor
    Model:      Dependency 'componentSelector' type 'Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.ITypedFactoryComponentSelector'
    Dependency: Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll
```

I think this part is important, so I'm pointing it out:

> Castle.Windsor Warning: 0 : Exception when resolving optional dependency Dependency 'JsonResultFactory' type 'CompanyName.Web.Mvc.ICustomJsonResultFactory' on component CompanyName.Web.OrderProcessing.Controllers.PickTicketController., Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException: ComponentActivator: could not proxy CompanyName.Web.Mvc.ICustomJsonResultFactory ---> System.ArgumentException: Component CompanyName.Web.Mvc.ICustomJsonResultFactory is not a typed factory. TypedFactoryInterceptor only works with typed factories.

```
   at Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.Internal.TypedFactoryInterceptor.SetInterceptedComponentModel(ComponentModel target)
at Castle.Windsor.Proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.SetOnBehalfAware(IOnBehalfAware onBehalfAware, ComponentModel target)
at Castle.Windsor.Proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.ObtainInterceptors(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
at Castle.Windsor.Proxy.DefaultProxyFactory.Create(IKernel kernel, Object target, ComponentModel model, CreationContext context, Object[] constructorArguments)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, ConstructorCandidate constructor, Object[] arguments)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ExtendedHandler.InvokeResolvePipeline(Int32 extensionIndex, ResolveInvocation invocation)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ExtendedHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<InvokeResolvePipeline>b__5()
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ResolveInvocation.Proceed()
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ComponentLifecycleExtension.Intercept(ResolveInvocation invocation)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ExtendedHandler.InvokeResolvePipeline(Int32 extensionIndex, ResolveInvocation invocation)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.ExtendedHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.ObtainPropertyValue(CreationContext context, PropertySet property, IDependencyResolver resolver)
```

I've tried adding the `Release` method to the controller per Windsor's example.  I also tried having the factory's `Create` return an interface instead of a `JsonResult`.  I've tried going through the Windsor source using ILSpy to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?  I think I'm following the example pretty closely... is the problem in my code, or in Windsor?

I'm using version 3.2.0 of the various Castle libraries with .Net 4.5.

Comment: The error mentions JsonResultFactory.  What is that?

Comment: Are any other components registered with the container?

Comment: Also, I don't think you need `FactorySupportFacility` if you're using `TypedFactoryFacility`. Perhaps try removing `FactorySupportFacility`?

Comment: @PhilSandler, there isn't a `JsonResultFactory`.  Only the interface.  I noticed that too and don't know where its coming from either.

Comment: @ChrisMantle, I am registering other components.  On your suggestion I removed the `FactorySupportFacility`.  I don't think the log is any different.

Comment: Should I make a small example that can fully replicate the problem?  I didn't think it was necessary when asking the question; I'm beginning to question that decision now.

Comment: Yes, that would be useful. We can try to replicate it locally.

Comment: Hmm, what could that JsonResultFactory error be coming from then?  I don't see how Windsor could have come up with that name on its own.

Comment: On a hunch I changed the name of the property on my base controller.  That `JsonResultFactory` is the name of the property.

Comment: Looks like this is where the error comes from.  Seems impossible that it would fail based on your code vs. the code example.  Have you tried a full clean and rebuild, or starting a new empty project and pasting the sample code there?

Comment: I'm working on creating a small console app.  Thus far I haven't been able to reproduce it though.

Comment: I figured it out.  In my question I said I installed the facility before registering my components.  That was incorrect.  I'm registering it *after* registering my typed factory.  I feel stupid now.  :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out I was installing the facility after registering my factory component.  I thought it was before all my components, but I was mistaken.  You have to install the facility first.  I wrongly expected an exception in `AsFactory()` if the facility wasn't yet installed.

Here is a complete program that reproduces the issue.

```
public interface IFooFactory {   IFoo Create();   }
public interface IFoo        {   void DoFoo();    }

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I pity the foo");
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public IFooFactory MyFooFactory { get; set; }

    public void DoBar()
    {
        var foo = MyFooFactory.Create();
        foo.DoFoo();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Bar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IFooFactory>().AsFactory());
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        var bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
        bar.DoBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Just have a similar issue ...In your answer, you stated that the code snippet is "a complete program that reproduces the issue." Wouldn't that imply that it isnt the correct implementation?

Comment: Yes, it reproduces the issue.  Read the comments above the code.  "You have to install the facility first."  If you edit the code following the comments, you will fix the issue.  It's pretty clear.  Move the `AddFacility` line up above the components.  Fixed.  Even the comments under the question address this.